# Worker could not connect to master (invalid assocation) on same machine - even though url is correct

Tags: apache-spark

The spark master log includes the following:

> 15/05/19 21:05:19 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on
>   addresses :[**akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn.local:7077**]

But the Worker is not able to connect:

> 15/05/19 21:27:13 INFO Worker: Connecting to master
>   akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn.local:7077/user/Master... 15/05/19
>   21:27:13 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote
>   address [**akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn.local:7077**]. Address is now
>   gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to
>   dead letters. Reason: Connection refused:
>   mellyrn.local/25.101.19.24:7077 15/05/19 21:27:25 INFO Worker:
>   Retrying connection to master (attempt # 1) 15/05/19 21:27:25 INFO
>   Worker: Connecting to master
>   akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn.local:7077/user/Master... 15/05/19
>   21:27:25 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote
>   address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn.local:7077]. Address is now
>   gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to
>   dead letters. Reason: Connection refused:
>   mellyrn.local/25.101.19.24:7077

Any hints what to try here?

Comment: This may happen if hostname entry is wrong, ie worker is not able to resolve IP->hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears these errors were ***intermittent*** - and due to the ***host machine was completely out of memory at the time***.  After shutting down some unrelated memory hogging processes the above errors mostly went away.

There still is a ***delay in achieving the Master/Worker association*** on order of a few tens of seconds that I would like to understand.

Note that there were not any log messages describing the low memory situation.

Comment: I have the same issue when I use spark-submit in YARN. However, in my case memory is not a problem. But the error happens quite frequently. Possibly this is a network issue or maybe AppMaster (spark driver) is terminated due to some error.

Comment: What is the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Check your file `conf/spark-defaults.conf`, set `spark.master` to `spark://mellyrn.local:7077`

Also, remember to configure ssh access without password.

`$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa`

`$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Thx but these are basic settings that were already in place (i have been doing spark for 18 months)